# Smallest subarray with sum equal to k

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I want to find the length smallest subarray whose sum is equal to k.

```
Input: arr[] = {2, 4, 6, 10, 2, 1}, K = 12 
Output: 2
```

Explanation:
All possible subarrays with sum 12 are `{2, 4, 6}` and `{10, 2}`.

```
Input: arr[] = { 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1 }, K = 7
Output: 2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what result have you gotten?

Comment: Contiguous subarray?

Comment: Assuming contiguous, use two pointers, keeping track of the subarray sum between the pointers and recording the distance whenever you get a new min subarray size that meets your target. This is linear time. Decide which pointer to advance based on which side of the target you're on.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an O(n) complexity approach using Hashing in Python:

```
#Using defaultdict for implementation of hashmap
from collections import defaultdict

def smallestSubarrayLength(arr, k): # 'k' is the target sum variable
    #Initializing the hashmap with zeros
    prevSum = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    
    #Variable which will store the smallest length subarray
    smallestLength = float('inf')
    
    curSum = 0 #Will store the current sum while iterating throught the array
    start = 0 # Specifies the start position for the specific subarray
    
    for end in range(len(arr)): #I used the variable name 'end' specifically because it specifies the end index of the subarray, just like 'start'
        
        curSum += arr[end] #Incrementing curSum
        
        #Checking if curSum is equal to the target sum
        if curSum == k:
            # Here, 'end - start + 1' is the length of the subarray
            if smallestLength > end - start + 1:
                smallestLength = end - start + 1
        
        #If curSum exceeds the target sum
        if curSum-k in prevSum:
            start = prevSum[curSum-k]+1
            # Here, 'end - start + 1' is the length of the subarray
            if smallestLength > end - start + 1:
                smallestLength = end - start + 1
        #As we store values in a hashmap using key-value pairs, here the key is prevSum[cursum], and the value is the index(i.e. 'end' variable)
        prevSum[curSum] = end
    
    if smallestLength == float('inf'): #If there was no smallest subarray
        return -1
    return smallestLength #Return the smallest subarray length
    
print(smallestSubarrayLength([1, 1, 1], 4))
```

I built this solution based on a similar question which was to find all subarrays from an array with sum equal to a target.
This is the link for the question: https://leetcode.com/problems/subarray-sum-equals-k

Solution: https://leetcode.com/problems/subarray-sum-equals-k/submissions/980057445/

Answer (score 0):

You can use an algorithm that finds a subset in size K, and save another variable that stores the number of members that make up such a subarray.

The algorithm for finding a K subarray is:

1. initialize an array of size K, Each place (idx) indicates whether there is a subarray that amounts to idx (I used a dictionary)
2. Go over any number (i) in the array, and any sum (j) we can reach in the previous iteration now we can reach j + i.
3. If in the K place it is marked TRUE, then there is a subarray that amounts to K.

Here's the solution in Python

```
def foo(arr,k):
    dynamic = {0:0}
    for i in arr:
        temp = {}
        for j, l in dynamic.items():
            if i + j <= k: # if not it's not interesting us
                # choose the smallest subarray
                temp[i+j] = min(l+1,dynamic.get(i+j,len(arr)))
        dynamic.update(temp)
    return dynamic.get(k,-1)
```

**the complexity is O(N*K).**

I assumed that the subarray refers to any possible combinations of original array.

---

Here is a Python code that solves the problem ***under the condition that the subset must be contiguous***:

**in O(N) complexity**

```
def shortest_contiguous_subarray(arr,k):
    if k in arr:
        return 1
    n = len(arr)
    sub_length = float('inf')
    sub = arr[(i:=0)]
    j = 1
    while j < n:
        while sub < k and j < n:
            sub += arr[j]
            j += 1
        while sub > k:
            sub -= arr[i]
            i += 1
        if sub == k:
            # print(arr[i:j],j-i)
            sub_length = min(sub_length,j-i)
            sub -= arr[i]
            i += 1
    return sub_length if sub_length <= n else -1
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such thing as "O(N*K)".
If K is an independent scalar (which it isn't in your code), then it's O(n),
it depends on "N", so it's O(n^2).
Same for second code: O(n^2).

Comment: You're not right:
For the first code see here: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subset-sum-problem-dp-25/?ref=lbp]
The algorithm passes with each element from the array on all places from 0 to K. So: O (N * K)
Also regarding the second code the algorithm there is based on Caterpillar method and the iteration is on each element a maximum of twice

Comment: I'm not arguing - I don't know exactly how to determine complexity, however, I've never seen O(n*k) => k*O(n) => O(n) for k not depending on n OR O(n^2)...
The page at link says "Given a set of non-negative integers" which doesn't necessarily apply to this question - yet, I don't know if it matters...

Comment: You're right that in the case of negative numbers the code needs to be changed a bit.
You can remove the condition `if i + j <= k:` and then it seems to me it will be fine.
But regarding complexity it is very simple: if the input length (N) increases linearly and K does not change, the number of calculations will also increase linearly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using JavaScript.
It could be made more efficient, for sure, but I've coded it to work.

```js
function lengthOfShortestSubArrayOfSumK(array, k) {
  var combos=[];
  for(var i=0; i<Math.pow(2, array.length); i++) {
    var bin=("0".repeat(array.length)+i.toString(2)).slice(-array.length).split("");
    var ones=bin.reduce((count, digit)=>{count+=digit=="1";return count;},0);
    var sum=bin.reduce((sum, digit, index)=>{sum+=digit=="1"?array[index]:0;return sum;},0);
    combos.push([bin, ones, sum]);
  };
  return combos.filter(combo=>combo[2]==k).sort((a, b)=>a[1]-b[1])[0][1];
}

var arraysAndKs=[
  {array:[2, 4, 6, 10, 2, 1], k:12},
  {array:[1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1], k:7}
];

for(arrayAndK of arraysAndKs)
  console.log("Length of shortest sub array of ["+arrayAndK.array.join(", ")+"] with sum "+arrayAndK.k+" is : "+lengthOfShortestSubArrayOfSumK(arrayAndK.array, arrayAndK.k));
```

The Binary number between `0` and `array.length` squared will give us a representation of included array items in the sum.
We count how many "ones" are in that Binary number.
We sum array items masked by those "one"s.
We save into `combos` array an array of the Binary number, "one"s count, and sum.
We filter `combos` for sum k, sort by count of "one"s, and retrun the first's "one"s count.

I'm sure this can be translated to any programming language.

Comment: This is a very expensive way of calculating the answer; for an array of 10 elements, it would require 2^10 loop iterations (O(n^2)). Given that linear-time answers exist, there is no excuse for such a high cost, asides from a certain "cool" factor.

Comment: "for an array of 10 elements, it would require 2^10 loop iterations" - no, 10^2.
Is that what you meant/typo?

Comment: "Given that linear-time answers exist" - "Given"?!?
"linear-time" == O(n)?!?

Comment: "very expensive" - please quantify...
"more complex" = ok, "very expensive" = no meaning...

Comment: Yes, it was a typo - I meant O(2^n). Yes, linear-time, O(n) answers exist if a contiguous interval is being sought (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64419079/15472). Yes, even if the interval need not be contiguous, your answer is way too expensive (= exponential time is horrible), and could be significantly improved using backtracking and minimal pruning (for example, no need to continue adding elements once K is exceeded; or no need to explore big sets if a small-set answer has been found)

Answer (score 0):

This answer works for any array of positive numbers, and can be modified to work with arrays that have zero or negative elements if an O(n) pre-processing pass is performed (1. find the minimum element `m, m <= 0`, 2. make the whole array positive by adding `-m+1` to all elements, 3. solve for `sum + n*(1-m)`)

```js
function search(input, goal) {    
    let queue = [ { avail: input.slice(), used: [], sum: 0 } ]; // initial state
    for (let qi = 0; qi < queue.length; qi ++) {
          let s = queue[qi]; // like a pop, but without using O(n) shift
        for (let i = 0; i < s.avail.length; i++) {        
            let e = s.avail[i];
            if (s.sum + e > goal) continue;               // dead end
            if (s.sum + e == goal) return [...s.used, e]; // eureka!!
            queue.push({                              // keep digging
                avail: [...s.avail.slice(0, i), ...s.avail.slice(i+1)], 
                used: [...s.used, e], 
                sum: s.sum + e 
            });
        }
    }
    return undefined; // no subset of input adds up to goal
}

console.log(search([2, 4, 6, 10, 2, 1], 12))
```

This is a classic breadth-first-search that does a little bit of pruning when it detects that we are already over the target sum. It can be further optimized to avoid exploring the same branch several times (for example, `[4,2]` is equivalent to `[2,4]`) - but this would require extra memory to keep a set of "visited" states. Additionally, you could add heuristics to explore more promising branches first.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by using unordered_map in c++. Hope this helps .

```
`


/* smallest subarray of sum k*/

#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

vector <int> v = {2,4,6,10,2,12};

int k=12;

unordered_map<int,int>m;

int start=0,end=-1;

int len=0,mini=INT_MAX;

int currsum=0;

for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){

    currsum+=v[i];

    if(currsum==k){
        start=0,end=i;
        len=end-start+1;
        mini=min(mini,len);

    }
    if(v[i]==k){
        mini=min(mini,1);
    }
    if(m.find(currsum-k)!=m.end()){
        end=i;
        start=m[(currsum-k)]+1;
        len=end-start+1;
        mini=min(mini,len);
    }
    m[currsum]=i;
}

  cout<<mini;

return 0;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution
{
    static int findSubArraySum(int arr[], int N, int k)
    {

        // code here
        // i use prefix sum and hashmap approach 
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        
        map.put(0,1);
        // this is bcoz when 1st element is valid one
        
        int count=0;
        int sum=0;
        
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            sum += arr[i];
            // prefix sum
            
            if(map.containsKey(sum-k)){
                count += map.get(sum-k);
            }
            
            
            map.put(sum, map.getOrDefault(sum,0)+1);
            
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

// this approach even for -ve numbers
// i came to dis solution by prefix sum approach

Answer (score 0):

This version finds the entire optimal sub-array, not only its length. It's based on a recursion. It will test each number of the array against the optimal sub-array of the rest.

```js
const bestSum = (targetSum, numbers) => {

  var shortestCombination = null

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    var current = numbers[i];

    if (current == 0) {
      continue
    }

    if (current == targetSum) {
      return [current]
    }

    if (current > targetSum) {
      continue;
    }

    // "remove" current from array
    numbers[i] = 0;

    // now the recursion:
    var rest = bestSum(targetSum - current, numbers)
    if (rest && (!shortestCombination || rest.length + 1 < shortestCombination.length)) {
      shortestCombination = [current].concat(rest);
    }

    // restore current to array
    numbers[i] = current

  }

  return shortestCombination
}

console.log(bestSum(7, [5, 3, 4, 7])) // Should be 7, not  [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code in Python 3. I used the same idea of find the longest subarray with a sum equal to K. But in the below code for every prefix sum I am storing the recent index.

```
def smallestSubArraySumLength(a, n, k):
    d=defaultdict(lambda:-1)
    d[0]=-1
    psum=0
    maxl=float('inf')
    for i in range(n):
       psum+=a[I]
       if psum-k in d:
          maxl=min(maxl, i-d[psum-k])
       d[psum]=i
    return maxl
```

Comment: There's a typo in the line ```psum+=a[I]```; the capital I should be lower-case i.  Other than that, very nice!

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Solution
  {
  static int findSubArraySum(int Arr[], int N, int k)
  {
  int min=-1;
  HashMap<Integer,Integer>map=new HashMap<>();
  sum=0;
  int ans=0;
  map.put(sum,1);
  int i=0;
  while(i<N)
  {
  sum+=arr[i];
  int re=sum-k;
  if(map.containsKey(re))
  {
  ans+=map.get(re);
  min=Math.min(min,i-map.get(re));
  }
  map.put(sum,map.getOrDefault(sum,0)+1);
  i++;
  }
  return min;
  }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution
      {
        static int findSubArraySum(int arr[], int N, int k)
        {  

        // code here
        // i use prefix sum and hashmap approach 
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        
        map.put(0,1);
        // this is bcoz when 1st element is valid one
        
        int count=0;
        int sum=0;
        
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            sum += arr[i];
            // prefix sum
            
            if(map.containsKey(sum-k)){
                count += map.get(sum-k);
            }
            
            
              map.put(sum, map.getOrDefault(sum,0)+1);
            
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```